# silverlight picking basic instead of wsHttpBinding

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

When I add a service silverlight is picking basic instead of wsHttpBinding.  What might cause this and how can I avoid it?  This is my web.config:

```
<configuration>
        <system.web>
            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        </system.web>

        <system.serviceModel>
            <standardEndpoints />
            <bindings />
            <services>
                <service name="Service2">
                    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="Service2Endpoint"
                        bindingName="wsHttpBindingFirst" contract="IService2" />
                </service>
            </services>
            <behaviors>
                <serviceBehaviors>
                    <behavior name="">
                        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                    </behavior>
                </serviceBehaviors>
            </behaviors>
            <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
        </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't put the namespace in
Not supported by silverlight